# Adding a value to the AX register but using AH and AL

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

In this assembly (8086) code what will be the value of each of these registers: **BL**, **AH** and **AL**

This is the code:

```
MOV AX, 1900
MOV BL, AH
INC AL
```

Comment: You should be able to do this yourself. If not, try it in a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

`AX = AL + AH * 256`

That means that `BL` is somewhere around `1900 / 256` give or take, plus one.

The rest is in `AL`.

This is true, because if `AX=256`, then `AL=0` and `AH=1`

`256 = 0 + 1 * 256`

`79 = 79 + 0 * 256`

`65535 = 256 * 256 - 1`

Comment: "65535 = 256 * 256 -1" Although this is correct, it's strange to see this in this context! Logically all these numerical examples illustrate the formula given in the first line (AX = AL + AH * 256). Therefore the last example should read: __65535 = 255 + 255 * 256__

Comment: Ha! Nice catch! Reading this I realised why I came up with it! For a whole week, just recently, I was trying to solve a `codegolf` and one line of my python code was `QuadWord[:] = 256*256*256*256-1`, being the last bit before the switch from `double-` to `quadword`. :D This way it was easier for my mind to map the bytes to their respective registers. :D